# Angular 8 Form control Ng If

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a requirement when `onclick` populate form field values.

I am facing problem with two form fields. Those two fields having `ngIf` check to hide and show. Hide and show is working fine.

But `formcontrol` value for that form fields are not populating like others.

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="50" class="pr-12" style="width:30%" *ngIf="frmStockReceive.supplierType ==='Supplier'">
  <mat-label>MFD Date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerr1" [(ngModel)]="frmStockReceive.mfdDate" formControlName="mfdDate" required name="txtMfdDate" placeholder="MFD Date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerr1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #pickerr1></mat-datepicker>
  <mat-error>MFD Date is required!</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
  mfdDate: new FormControl(new Date(reciveItem.mfdDate), [Validators.required]),
  supplierType: new FormControl(reciveItem.supplierType, [Validators.required]),
  expiryInMonths: new FormControl(reciveItem.expiryInMonths, [Validators.required]),
});
```

Comment: what is the problem , didn't understood ?

Comment: you should provide the related component.ts file too, in where the operations are occurring. Problem can't be find by looking only in the html file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using reactive forms you shouldn't be using [(ngModel)] to bind them. We can't see the full picture with mhat was shared, but you could try using [formControlName] (input variable style), and also ensure the form control value is being set properly before you try to render the template (do some debugging/logging after the creation of the formgroup via myForm.value). Lastly, I'd make sure this mat-form-field is nested in the html underneath an element where you define your form via [formGroup]="myForm".

Best of luck, post more info if you are still stuck
Happy Coding!